# How to set external clang directory as default gcc in macports for subsequent port installations?

Tags: macos, clang, macports

I downloaded the clang compiler directly from the prebuilt binary tar provided on the llvm website [here](http://llvm.org/releases/3.9.0/clang+llvm-3.9.0-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.xz). The tar file contains a standard directory hierarchy with `bin`, `include`, `lib` etc. Now I want to configure `macports` to use this compiler in such a way that when a subsequent port requires clang then this compiler's binary is used. Note that **I do not want** `macports` to download and install *a separate copy* of `clang`. *Is it possible to do so?*

**DETAILS:** The reason why I want to keep the clang installation in a separate place is because I often use scientific code, or other code, like chromium, and I use anaconda. I also have `xcode` installed and that provides its own version of compilers. Adding macports' compilers to the system makes my system almost unmanageable because it is often very difficult to ensure that the right `runtime library` and `compilation time library` are being used.

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts does not support this, and there is also no unsupported way to get this done that I am aware of.

However, C++ software installed through MacPorts should always end up using the libc++ runtime (if you're on a system where it is the default). MacPorts is aware of the C++ runtime its ports use and tries to make sure all its ports use the runtime set as the `cxx_stdlib` in `macports.conf` (which defaults to your system's default).